# Laravel Relationship Find UUID

Tags: laravel, relationship, uuid

I have make a Trait for UUID. I use a lot of relationschip inside my code. On a relationship you can do `find()` and `findOrFail()` but i have write a code for `findU()` and `findUOrFail()` but i can't use it inside a relationship. How can i fix it?

Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Base\Traits;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

/**
 * Trait Uuids
 *
 * @package Modules\Core\Traits
 */
trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    public static function bootUuids ()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->uuid = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param $uuid
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function findU ($uuid)
    {
        return static::where('uuid', '=', $uuid)->first();
    }

    /**
     * @param $uuid
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function findUOrFail($uuid)
    {
        $post = static::where('uuid', '=', $uuid)->first();

        if( is_null($post) ) {
            return abort(404);
        } else {
            return $post;
        }
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
/**
     * Show
     */
    public function show(Request $request, $uuid)
    {
        return responder()->success($request->user()->projects()->findUOrFail($uuid))->respond();
    }
```

Error:
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\BelongsToMany::findUOrFail()`

Comment: Why you did not stay with the name `id` for the identifier?

Comment: Do you need the `id` ? Otherwise can set the primarykey as `uuid` It would be much easier

Comment: if you set $table->uuid('id')->primary(); at migration file you can use find() method for finding a specified model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need `id` since you're using `uuid`

In your migration file you need:

```
$table->uuid('uuid');
$table->primary('uuid');
```

In your model:

```
use Uuids;
protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
public $incrementing = false;
```

**Or much easier**

In your migration file:

```
$table->uuid('id');
$table->primary('id');
```

In your model:

```
use Uuids;
public $incrementing = false;
```

You don't need to override `findOrFail` or `find`

Answer (score 1):

It should help to have the function referenced directly in the model rather than trying to access it directly in a trait. I am assuming that you are including the Uuids trait above in your projects model. If so, try creating a method on the projects model like this:

```
public function tryFindUOrFail($uuid)
{
    return $this->findUOrFail($uuid);
}
```

Then you would write your show method as:

```
return responder()->success($request->user()->projects()->tryFindUOrFail($uuid))->respond();
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to include your method with the $appends array so that it is directly accessible through the relationship.